# Animation render problems

Tags: rendering, animation, armature, render-layers, layers

I have an animation with a layer for the background and a layer for the armature. Buy when i render animation, the character and armature appears gray.any ideas?[image: bad render with character gray]

[image: character colored in like it should be]

Comment: Are you using post-processing Compositor nodes?  If yes: show a screen-shot.  Or if willing, include your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: dunno about the nodes since they seem really complicated so i never touch them. heres the file any ways https://blend-exchange.com/b/ZGreRsks